# Programatically Add multiple simple product to cart not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to add multiple product to cart at the same time.

But it always add only single item with multiply of other product qty

suppose to be

```
Product id            qty
4                     6
5                     5
6                     4
```

it will add product id 4 with 15 qty.

Here is my code

```
    <?php
namespace Kite\Boxes\Controller\Category;
 class Addpack extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

         /**
          * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
          */
         protected $cart;
         /**
          * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
          */
         protected $product;
         protected $resultPageFactory;

         public function __construct(
             \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
             \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
             \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
             \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
         ) {
             $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
             $this->cart = $cart;
             $this->product = $product;
             parent::__construct($context);
         }
         public function execute()
         {
             try {
                $postedData = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
                //echo "<pre/>";print_r($postedData['multi_add']);exit;
                foreach ($postedData['multi_add'] as $productId => $qty) {
                  if($qty>0){
                     $params = array();
                     $params['qty'] = $qty;//product quantity
                     $_product = $this->product->load($productId);
                       if ($_product) {
                           $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
                           $this->cart->save();
                        }
                   }
                }


                 $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Add to cart successfully.'));
             } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                 $this->messageManager->addException(
                     $e,
                     __('%1', $e->getMessage())
                 );
             } catch (\Exception $e) {
                 $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('error.'));
             }
             /*cart page*/
             $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/checkout/cart/index');


         }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following code

```
namespace Kite\Boxes\Controller\Category;

class Addpack extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $cartRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * Addpack constructor.
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $postedData = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
            //echo "";print_r($postedData['multi_add']);exit;
            foreach ($postedData['multi_add'] as $productId => $qty) {
                if($qty>0){
                    $params = array();
                    $params['qty'] = $qty;//product quantity
                    $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
                    if ($product->getId()) {
                        $quote->addProduct(
                            $product,
                            intval($qty)
                        );
                    }
                }
            }

            $this->cartRepository->save($quote);
            $this->checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote)->unsLastRealOrderId();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Add to cart successfully.'));
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException(
                $e,
                __('%1', $e->getMessage())
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('error.'));
        }
        /*cart page*/
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/checkout/cart/index');


    }
}
```

Comment: now Cart added with 0 price qty is ok

Comment: First product price is going correct rest product added with 0 price

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: It just redirect to cart page without adding item to cart with success message

Comment: I just updated code, check now. Working fine for me.

Comment: it add with 0 Price in cart

Comment: don't know first time it was not working.Working now thank you very much @sohel

Comment: Check something wrong with other module. It's working fine for default M22.

Comment: Its works fine on cart but it doesn't update minicart :(

Comment: Fire minicart after done. like https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Checkout/etc/frontend/sections.xml

Comment: @SohelRana fire minicart not working.